# grunt compass Error: invalid option --sourcemap

Tags: sass, gruntjs, invalidation

i run grunt dev and get the error:

```
Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
Error: invalid option: --sourcemap
```

Don´t know why :(
Don´t even know how i could run compass without the option ... found nothing in the gruntfile.

thanks for help, i´m new with grunt/compass/sass

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Execute "**gem list**" so we can have more details on what gem versions you're using.

AFAIK the sourcemap works since **sass 3.3** and up.

If you want to disable the sourcemap on your project, check your **config.rb** file and check the sass_options entry, you might find "**:sourcemap => true**". If you find it, remove it and check it out.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

This happens because of old version of SASS (or COMPASS, if you are using it) ruby gems which do not support sourcemap options.

Update these with following commands:

```
gem update sass
gem update compass    <= if applicable
```

This should resolve the issue.